# Implement own version of ChromeCast/SmartCast

Tags: linux, fedora, chromecast

So my current OS, Fedora 35, doesn't appear to have casting capabilities. I have a vizio TV that supports conventional casting (i.e. I can cast to it from my Mac devices and Android phones), and would like to implement my own casting utility for my Fedora laptop.
What protocols would I need to know and implement?

I assume there is a "casting request" packet that has to be sent from client, a "casting accept" from the TV, and then a continuous stream (TCP?) of the screen contents that are casted.

From wireshark it is clear the vizio tv is using MDNS to locate devices in its vicinity.

Apparently the protocol used is Google Cast, and the basics of it are in [this](https://blog.oakbits.com/google-cast-protocol-overview.html) article series.

Comment: First take a look at what's available. You might get some inspiration https://www.linuxuprising.com/2020/04/how-to-cast-your-gnome-shell-desktop-to.html

Comment: "... Fedora 35, doesn't appear to have casting capabilities."  I'm on Fedora 35 and I can cast tabs and the screen from Google Chrome, videos with vlc, etc.  What/how do you want to cast?

Comment: I had in mind a full screen cast. It is good to know that Chrome and VLC works, though.